# Net::OpenSSH how to make perl script not exit and move to next IP if authentication fails

Tags: perl, openssh

I am a beginner to Perl. My objective is to run a loop on a list of router IPs and attempt to ssh login into them, execute some commands, and store the output.

Upon unsuccessful authentication of one router IP, the entire script stops, and it does not move to the next IP. I wish to store why authentication failed of the router IP in question, and then move onto the next IP to execute.

The error I get before the script exits is:

> Unable to connect: unable to establish master SSH connection: bad
> password or master process exited unexpectedly

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

use Net::OpenSSH;

my $password = "xxxxxxx";
my $s;
$filename1 = "ip_FINAL_sample";

open my $f1, '<', "$filename1.txt";
chomp(my @file1 = <$f1>);
close $f1;

for $loopvariable(@file1)
{
    my @mikparameters = split /\|/, $loopvariable;
    $mikip = $mikip . $mikparameters[0] . "\n"; 
}

my @routers = split "\n", $mikip;

my $cmd1 = 'system identity print';
my $cmd2 = 'system routerboard print';

foreach $s (@routers)
{
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("yyyyy+500w\@$s", password=>$password, timeout=>30);
    $ssh->error and die "Unable to connect: " . $ssh->error;
    print "connected to $s\n";
    
    my $fh1 = $ssh->pipe_out($cmd1) or die "Unable to run command\n";
    my $fh1_1 = $ssh->capture($cmd1) or die "Unable to run command\n";
    
    my $fh2 = $ssh->pipe_out($cmd2) or die "Unable to run command\n";
    my $fh2_2 = $ssh->capture($cmd2) or die "Unable to run command\n";
        
    while (<$fh1>) 
    {
        print "$_";
    }
    close $fh1;
    print "\n";
        
    open my $file1, '>>', "output.txt" or die "Can't open output.txt: $!\n";
    print $file1 "$fh1_1";
    close $file1;
    
    while (<$fh2>) 
    {
        print "$_";
    }
    close $fh2;
    print "\n";
        
    open my $file2, '>>', "output.txt" or die "Can't open output.txt: $!\n";
    print $file2 "$fh2_2";
    close $file2;
    
    

        
    undef $ssh;
    
}
```

Comment: You mentioned authentication errors, but I believe you mean all errors? If so, replace `die` with `warn` and `next`. Or wrap the loop body with an `eval` and `warn`.

Comment: Just in case: this is the line they are talking about: `$ssh->error and die "Unable to connect: " . $ssh->error;`.  It says that if there is `$ssh->error` then (`and`) run `die ...`, which exits the program unless all that is placed inside `eval { ... }`.  Or, simpler, instead of that `or die...` have `or do { warn "Unable to connect..."; next };`

Comment: In order to run a command and sent its output to a file you can use `$ssh->system({stdout_fh => $file1}, $cmd)`.

Comment: Check also [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel)!